# Getting "InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records." after updating Amplify Users IAM Keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-amplify, sts

I recently "Created a new Access Key" for my AWS Amplify IAM user, and disabled the old key. I also changed how I was authenticating to AWS (using an IAM user now instead of previously a SSO Federated user).

Now when I run something like:

`amplify api push`

I get:

`InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`

I tried re-running:

`amplify configure`

I used `aws configure` to set the new Access Key to the default profile, but still no luck.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up checking `local-aws-info.json` in the `amplify/config` directory and noticed that the "useProfile"  and "profileName" keys weren't accurate anymore.

To fix I ran:

`amplify configure project`

And once that finished, I ran:

`amplify pull` however, this was probably only necessary due to the hacking around I did trying to fix the error originally.